# Is there a term for being able to understand a Kanji meaning, but unable to pronounce it?

Tags: meaning, word-requests

Is there a term for being able to understand a Kanji meaning, but unable to pronounce it in Japanese?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I believe there is no single-word term for this. There is a word 難読語【なんどくご】 that means "hard-to-read word", but it doesn't mean "being able to understand its meaning". You can say something like 意味は分かるけど読めない. (Even native speakers encounter such examples often!)